# Assigning values for Nullable<Guid>

Tags: c#, nullable

I am trying a create a variable Guid? which represents a nullable db column. I am facing issues while assigning values. I was able to assign null to the variable easily. But when I want to assign a Guid value I have to create a new Guid? object which doesn't accept the string.

```
Guid? sample=new Guid?(someString); // erroing "Cannot implicitly convert string to Guid"
```

So I have to do like this

```
Guid? sample=new Guid?(new Guid(someString)); // working code
```

I am also assigning values conditionally.

```
Guid? sample=(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(someString))?null: new Guid?(new Guid(someString));
```

Why is this issue coming up with Guid ?

Comment: `new Guid(someString)` will never return null - why are you using a nullable here?

Comment: @PrestonGuillot: The value of `sample` could be changed later on. We are just seeing the initialization in the question.

Comment: @Preston I have updated the code explaining the scenario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Guid? sample = new Guid?(new Guid(someString));
```

This does not really make much sense. You have a nullable type to be able to store a null value. But when you are assigning a value *anyway*, then it won’t be null. A type’s constructor will actually *never* return null, so `new Guid(someString)` will always return a valid `Guid`—or throw an exception of course. As such, you can just assign the resulting `Guid` to the variable of nullable type:

```
Guid? sample = new Guid(someString);
```

If you want to consider invalid input, e.g. if `someString` is null or simply not a valid `Guid`, then you can use [`Guid.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tryparse.aspx) (.NET 4.0 or higher):

```
Guid? sample = null;
Guid parsed;
if (Guid.TryParse(someString, out parsed))
    sample = parsed;
```

Note that this will allow you to remove any other check on `someString` too. You can pass a null string or anything else in, and `TryParse` will just return false, keeping `sample`’s default value.

Comment: `TryParse()` is a much better solution then only checking if `IsNullOrWhitespace()`.

Comment: @poke - thanks for the suggesstion. I am using that now.

Answer (score 6):

> But when I want to assign a Guid value I have to create a new Guid? object which doesn't accept the string.

You can shorten your code to :

```
Guid? sample= new Guid(someString);
```

Nullable Types can be assigned the `<T>` type directly.

```
int? i = 1; 
int? i2 = null;

bool? b = true;
bool? b2 = null;
```

Comment: Thanks Eric. But I am getting an error using the conditional statement saying "Type of conditional statement cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between <null> and System.Guid". I also checked the type of Guid and it seems to be struct. Is that making some difference here ?

Comment: Check out [poke's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21767541/209259), for checking the value before assignment it's best to TryParse() the value.  It was my assumption you had valid input before you modified your question.

Answer (score 2):

Because `Guid` has a constructor that takes `string` parameter.But nullable Guid (Guid?) takes only `Guid` as parameter.